# Passport authentication callback hangs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, passport.js

After hours trying to solve this by myself I reach to SO community looking for some light.

I'm using passport for user authentication. It's already initialized in my main express.js file as per the docs:

```
app.use(passport.initialize());
```

I got a index.js file which handles `facebook-passport` in this manner:
Index.js

```
'use strict';

import express from 'express';
import passport from 'passport';
import auth from '../auth.service';
let router = express.Router();

//this function is defined in the auth.service import but copied it here in case it's needed (the `signToken` is also defined in the service)
function setTokenCookie(req, res) {
  if (!req.user) return res.json(404, { message: 'Something went wrong, please try again.'});
  var token = signToken(req.user._id, req.user.role);
  res.cookie('token', JSON.stringify(token));
  res.redirect('/');
}


router
  .get('/', passport.authenticate('facebook', {
    scope: ['email', 'user_about_me'],
    failureRedirect: '/login'
  }))

.get('/callback', passport.authenticate('facebook', {
  successRedirect: '/',
  failureRedirect: '/login'
}), setTokenCookie);

module.exports = router;
```

And the passport.js that's being imported in the index.js in this manner:

passport.js

```
import passport from 'passport';
import {
  Strategy as FacebookStrategy
}
from 'passport-facebook';

exports.setup = function(User, config) {
  passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
      clientID: config.facebook.clientID,
      clientSecret: config.facebook.clientSecret,
      callbackURL: config.facebook.callbackURL
    },
    function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
      User.findOne({
        'facebook.id': profile.id
      }, (findErr, user) => {
        if (findErr) {
          return done(findErr);
        }
        if (!user) {
          let userToSave = new User({
            name: profile.displayName,
            email: profile.emails[0].value,
            role: 'user',
            username: profile.username,
            provider: 'facebook',
            facebook: profile._json
          });
          userToSave.save((saveErr) => {
            if (saveErr) done(saveErr);
            return done(null, user);
          });
        } else {
          return done(null, user);
        }
      });
    }
  ));
};
```

This is what currently happens:

- Facebook login is prompted
- After successful authentication in Facebook the callback (/auth/facebook/callback) IS reached with user info and token as expected.
- User is saved in DB with expected fields

Where things get weird:

- After saving the User, the `done(null,user)` does nothing. The app hangs on the callback and client keeps waiting for response.
- The middleware setTokenCookie never gets called so the problem is definitely in the previous step.

What I've tried:

- Wrapping the whole setup function from `passport.js` in a process.tick (found some people use it but didn't resolve the issue)
- Using Mongoose with promise as in `User.findOne({...}).exec().then(user => {...})`

If you need additional information please don't hesitate to ask. Any help is really appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you call mongoose.connect()?

Comment: Yes :). Everything regarding Mongoose, works as expected, the user is either Saved or Retrieved from DB, but in both cases when done(null, user) is called it hangs.

Comment: How are you determining that setTokenCookie is not executing? Do you just have console.logs everywhere?

Comment: I got node-debug hooked, I've also tried with console.log(). But anyway if it  were being executed I would atleast get some response.

Comment: Did you figure this one out? I'm stuck with the same problem, and now I can't sleep.

Comment: stuck with the same issue. :-(

Answer (score 1):

I see a few possible missing pieces glancing at my code. Are you using the  `passport.session()` middleware? Also the `serializeUser` and `deserializeUser` functions?

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  //place user's id in cookie
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  //retrieve user from database by id
  User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
    done(err, user);
  });
});
```

Comment: Hello @cody . Yes I've tried using the `passport.session()` and also removing it and adding the `{session: false}` option to the Passport strategy. Regarding those functions, were are they invoked? Are they necessary?

Comment: `serializeUser` will be called after a user successfully logs in through facebook to make the user.id available in the cookie for subsequent requests. `deserializeUser` is used on those subsequent requests to allow you to retrieve the user from your datastore. I believe you want to use them in your scenario with the `passport.session()` middleware. I'm pretty sure passport expects them to be used for everything except for services which you send credentials for with every request (usually API's).

Answer (score 1):

If you're a noob to passport/express like me, this may help:

check if you invoke done() in your passport logic:

```
passport.use(new twitchStrategy({
    clientID: config.twitchID,
    clientSecret: config.twitchSecret,
    /*to be updated*/
    callbackURL: config.callbackURL,
    scope: "user_read"
  },
  function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    console.log(profile);
    ***return done();***
  }
));
```